# Do antecedents have to be true for the entire universal quantifier or just 1 case?

Tags: logic

Sample:
$$∀x ∈ R+,∃y ∈ R+, x < y ⇒ x > y$$

Say I tried `y = 5`. Do I need to check if the consequent is true for just the x values less than 5?

Secondly, Since there is no value y that makes the antecedent true, is this statement true since there are no counter examples? The implication is never used.

I'm looking for a small explanation, rather than a solution (don't treat it like a homework question looking for an answer).

Comment: An help regarding the counter-intuitive aspects of the conditional: recall that $p \rightarrow q$ (in *classical* logic) is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$. Thus, we can rewrite $x<y \rightarrow x>y$ as $\lnot (x<y) \lor (x>y)$, i.e. as : $(x \ge y) \lor (x>y)$. Now it is easy "to see" why $\forall x \exists y[(x \ge y) \lor (x>y)]$ is always *true* : for $x$ whatever, it is enough to pick as $y$ the value of $x$ itself, and $x \ge x$ is always satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\forall x$ is *before* $\exists y$. This means that the $y$ you use is allowed to depend on $x$ -- you don't have to select a single $y$ that must work with all possible $x$.

What the formula says is that *once* someone chooses an $x$, *then* it is possible to find a particular $y$ that makes $x<y\Rightarrow x>y$ true.

Since $x<y$ and $x>y$ can't be true at the same time, $x<y\Rightarrow x>y$ is true exactly when $x<y$ is *false*. So in other words the entire formula is true if "for each $x$ there is a $y$ that is not greater than $x$". But this is clearly true -- for example we might take $y$ to be $x$ itself, or $\frac12 x$.

Comment: Oh, so I can prove this true by picking a y that depends on x?

Comment: @user83039: Yes -- that's what $\forall x\exists y$ means. If it had been $\exists y\forall x$ you would have to find a single $y$ that works with all possible $x$.

Comment: Yes, that is what the quantifier order means. In fact one can rewrite a statement which has existential quantifiers under universal quantifiers in terms of quantification over functions. That is, if you have $(\forall x \in A)(\exists y \in B) P(x,y)$, this is equivalent to $(\exists f : A \to B)(\forall x \in A) P(x,f(x))$. This formulation is useful sometimes. For example, when the statement is about continuity, the $f$ whose existence is claimed is called the modulus of continuity, which is a useful tool for assessing the quantitative smoothness of a function).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Your orders are actually in the wrong order, $x<y$ and $y>x$ are equivalent :)

Comment: @Ian: While that is "morally" right, it is not always technically true, depending on which mechanism we use to quantify over functions. For example in set theory the proposition that $(\forall x\in A)(\exists y\in B) y\in g(x)$ implies $(\exists f:A\to B)(\forall x\in A)f(x)\in g(x)$ is exactly the _axiom of choice_, so in set theory without AC your equivalence doesn't hold.

Comment: Darn, did I mess up the question. I mean't `x < y ⇒ x > y`. Nonetheless, your logic is helpful.

Comment: @user: You can edit your question to fix that.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Indeed, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "check if the consequent is true," but we can prove

$∀x ∈ R+:∃y ∈ R+: [x < y \implies P(x,y)]$

for *any* binary predicate $P$. As Henning pointed out, the required $y$ could be just $x$ itself.

The proof makes use of the following facts:

$\forall x: x=x$

$\forall x\in R+: \neg x\lt x$

Proof:

1. Suppose $a\in R+$
2. $a=a$
3. $\exists x:x=a$ (from 2)
4. $b=a$ (from 3, introducing $b$)
5. $b\in R+$ (from 1 and 4)
6. $\neg b\lt b$ (from 5)
7. Suppose $a\lt b$
8. $b\lt b$  (from 4 and 7)
9. $\neg b\lt b \implies P(a,b)$  (from 8)
10. $P$ (from 6 and 9)
11. $a\lt b \implies P(a,b)$ (from 7 and 10)
12. $\forall x:[x\in R+ \implies \exists y:[y\in R+ [\land \implies P(x,y)]]]$ (from 1 and 11)

or equivalently

$∀x ∈ R+:∃y ∈ R+: [x \lt y \implies P(x,y)]$